# Get exact value from elasticsearch results in python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, response

I am new to the elastic search and python and need some help.
I want elastic search to return the exact results like a SQL query does. In python-elasticsearch, I am getting the results as:

```
{u'_id': u'33',
 u'_index': u'data',
 u'_score': 1.0,
 u'_source': {u'business_id': u'P1fJb2WQ1mXoiudj8UE44w'},
 u'_type': u'business'}
```

Whereas I only need to extract the business_id i.e.'P1fJb2WQ1mXoiudj8UE44w'

How can I achieve this? Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You get a [python dictionary](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) returned. You can access the information as follows:

```
entry = {u'_id': u'33',
 u'_index': u'data',
 u'_score': 1.0,
 u'_source': {u'business_id': u'P1fJb2WQ1mXoiudj8UE44w'},
 u'_type': u'business'}
entry['_source']['business_id']
>> 'P1fJb2WQ1mXoiudj8UE44w'
```

If I remember correctly, if you are using elasticsearch-py you can supply a `fields` parameter, which specifies the fields you want to return in your search. More documentation about this can be found [here](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.search).